# EF Code First can't seed database [Console app]

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have a console app, I managed to create database using Code First but I can't seed any data. I use update-database in Package Manager Console to do it. Please help. I'm searching for hours. Here is my code:

/Models/ApplicationDbContext class:

```
namespace ToDoApp.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
           : base("ToDoApp")
        {
        Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
        }

        public DbSet<TestModel> Tests { get; set; }
    }

}
```

/Models/ApplicationDbInitializer class:

```
 public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
 {
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        context.Tests.AddOrUpdate(new TestModel()
        {
            Description = "Test1"
        });
       base.Seed(context);
    }
 }
```

/Models/TestModel class:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

/Program class:

```
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

/App.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <!--<contexts>
      <context type="ToDoApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext, ToDoApp">
        <databaseInitializer type="ToDoApp.Models.ApplicationDbInitializer, ToDoApp" />  
      </context>
    </contexts>--> <!-- This don't work -->
 </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
   <add key="DatabaseInitializerForType ToDoApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext, ToDoApp"
     value="ToDoApp.Models.ApplicationDbInitializer, ToDoApp" />
  </appSettings> <!-- This don't work also -->
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update-database` will run the **migration** Seed(). Your code is for the **initializer** Seed() which runs only when the database is created. See [here](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/) for an explanation of the differences.

Since you are using `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` it should run anytime your model changes. You could just delete the database. Otherwise, force a model change and then either access your context in code or call `context.Database.Initialize()` at startup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solved the problem. Indeed, update-database runs Migration Seed() but my data is in Initializer Seed(), so I need to call initializer at runtime (in my case Program.cs) in order for data to be seeded. You saved my day!

Comment: Also it looks like there is no need for changes in App.config file, so why in many tutorials there are changes in this file to run Initializer ? I made a new topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086184/entityframework-changes-in-app-config-file-for-database-initializer